# Getting the uncompressed image size

Tags: php, image, thumbnails, gd, filesize

I have a small PHP script which converts image files to thumbnails. The uploader I have has a 100MB max, which I'd like to keep.

The problem is, when opening the file, GD decompresses it, causing it to be huge and make PHP run out of memory (`Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 64000 bytes)`). I don't want to increase my memory any further than this allowed size.

I don't care about the image, I can just make it show a default thumbnail, that's fine. But I do need a way to catch the error `imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($file))` spawns when the image is too big.

Since the error spawned is fatal, it cannot be try-catched, and since it loads it in one command, I can't keep looking after it to make sure it's not approaching the limit. I need a way to calculate how big the image will be before trying to process it.

Is there a way to do this? `filesize` wouldn't work as it gives me the compressed size...

*My code is as follows:*

```
$image = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($newfilename));
$ifilename = 'f/' . $string . '/thumbnail/thumbnail.jpg';

$thumb_width = 200;
$thumb_height = 200;

$width = imagesx($image);
$height = imagesy($image);

$original_aspect = $width / $height;
$thumb_aspect = $thumb_width / $thumb_height;

if ( $original_aspect >= $thumb_aspect )
{
    // Image is wider than thumbnail.
    $new_height = $thumb_height;
    $new_width = $width / ($height / $thumb_height);
}
else
{
    // Image is taller than thumbnail.
    $new_width = $thumb_width;
    $new_height = $height / ($width / $thumb_width);
}

$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor( $thumb_width, $thumb_height );

// Resize and crop
imagecopyresampled($thumb,
                   $image,
                   0 - ($new_width - $thumb_width) / 2, // Center the image horizontally
                   0 - ($new_height - $thumb_height) / 2, // Center the image vertically
                   0, 0,
                   $new_width, $new_height,
                   $width, $height);
imagejpeg($thumb, $ifilename, 80);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried looking at the original image size before re-sizing? Maybe multiplying it by a set % based of average format compression?

```
$averageJPGFileRatio = 0.55;
$orgFileSize = filesize ($newfilename) * 0.55;
```

and looking at that before doing any work?

Secondary idea

Calculate it like this: `width * height * 3 = filesize`
The 3 is for the red, green, and blue values if you're working with images with an alpha channel use 4 instead of 3. This should give you a VERY close estimation of the bitmap size. Does not take into account header info, but that should be negligible at a few bytes.